# Disable access to sharepoint for all users - maintenance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

We are currently in the process of moving servers and would like no users to access SharePoint in the interim as the data is synced bidirectionally across SharePoint to the File server.

We are split from remote workers and onsite workers so they need to use the Terminal Server to update files while this transition happens.

Understandably not everyone will adhere to our email - is there a quick and easy way to turn off sharepoint online? or redirect all users to a holding page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your site Collection to Read only using site closure and deletion Policy.

Steps :

```
1.Sign in as a site owner.

2.Click Settings   and then click Site Settings. 

3.Under Site Administration, click Site Closure and Deletion.

4. To close the site, click Close this site now. To reopen it, click Open this site.
```

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-policies-for-site-closure-and-deletion-A8280D82-27FD-48C5-9ADF-8A5431208BA5

Before closure of site you can create Site Policy and apply to the site. Site policy we wil be create as below image.select the checkbox to make Site read only on Closure of the site
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the user from the site collection.

Navigate to site->site settings->people and groups->change the "MembershipGroupId=0" from the URL->you can choose the users and delete the users from the site collection:

[image]